# Passing data using VueJS to create a pricing plan table

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

This is my first foray into using VueJS so any pointers or better ways to tackle the problem are much appreciated. Here is where I am at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezBwJw

I'm building a pricing plan table where users can browse 4 different payment plans. The table is interactive, users have access to radio buttons which toggle between viewing prices in GBP & USD, as well as viewing the cost if they pay per year or per month. All of this is working, but the issue I now have is that I want to pass some data to a 'summary' section which will be presented to the user before they choose to sign up. The one piece of data I am struggling to pass to the summary table is the price.

When a user selects a plan I want the price that is currently showing in that plan to show in the 'Total to pay now' field. In jQuery I'd do something like this (simplified version of Codepen)...

```
<div>
  <h1>Basic</h1>
  <div class="price">7</div>
  <a href="#" class="select-plan">Select this plan</a>
</div>

<h2 class="total"></h2>


$('.select-plan').on('click', function() {
  var planName = $(this).parent().find('.price').text();
  $('.total').text(planName);
});
```

I'm currently using `v-if` to show the different prices for the respective plans, so I'm lost as to how I would get the item that is currently in view and pass that to the summary field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JQuery Way

One option is to create watchers that call an `updatePrice` method whenever a variable that effects the current price changes. For example:

```
watch: {
  'activePlan': 'updatePrice',
  'currency': 'updatePrice',
  'frequency': 'updatePrice'
},
```

... and then in `methods`:

```
updatePrice: function() {
   this.price = $('.price.' + this.activePlan).text();
 }
```

[Here is a fork  of your CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzbrLy) with that change. Notice that I've added the plan name as a class so that the JQuery selector can find the correct element.

## Component Way (do this!)

Personally, I think it you'd be better off taking a totally different approach. I would make [a custom component](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) for plans. This will let you encapsulates all the functionality you require in a reusable and manageable way.

For example, you could make a component like this

```
Vue.component('plan-component', {
  template: '#plan-component',

  props: ['frequency', 'name', 'priceYearly', 'priceMonthly'],

  computed: {
    'price': function() {
      // Move the logic for determining the price into the component
      if (this.frequency === 'year') {
        return this.priceYearly;
      } else {
        return this.priceMonthly;
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    makeActivePlan() {
      // We dispatch an event setting this to become the active plan
      // A parent component or the Vue instance would need to listen
      //   to this event and act accordingly when it occurs
      this.$dispatch('set-active-plan', this);
    }
  }
});
```

Components are related to an HTML template. So in your HTML you would need a template tag with id `plan-component`.

```
<template id="plan-component">
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  <div>
    <span>{{ price }}</span>
  </div>
  <a class="select-plan" v-on:click="makeActivePlan($event)" href="#">Select this plan</a>
</template>
```

Thus each plan gets its own component which handles the data related to that plan. And instead of repeating the same HTML for each plan in a table, you can just use your new custom `<plan-component>`, and bind the appropriate values to each plan (these are the `props`).

I've implemented this more fully as a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/m8rvhhb5/). I got rid of USB vs GBP currency because I wanted to keep things simple. I hope this gives you some idea about how to tackle your problem!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and JSFiddle's. This has really helped me understand the logic behind Vue.JS. You'll be pleased to know I'll be going down the component route.